# Remove tabs from jquery-ui-tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-theme

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/mYx5y/4/

I have created my own tab buttons which are connected with the jquery-ui-tabs.  I want to do this as it gives me easier freedom to style and move and arrange the tab buttons exactly how I want.

Now, I need to hide or remove the default tab buttons.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just hide them with JavaScript...

```
$( '.ui-tabs-nav' ).hide();
```

...or CSS.

```
.ui-tabs-nav {
  display: none;
}
```

You can remove the `.ui-tabs-nav` element since all the logic of the widget is stored in it.

You could also create your own tab engine.

Comment: This hides all the tabs not particular ones as asked